# Feeding a Variable alpha (learning rate) to ApplyGradientDescent

Tags: c++, tensorflow

This is a minimal example to create a variable, create a gradient for it and create the gradient update operations with ApplyGradientDescent

```
auto w = Variable(scope, { 3 }, DT_FLOAT);

std::vector<Output> grad_outputs;
TF_CHECK_OK(AddSymbolicGradients(scope, { loss }, { w }, &grad_outputs));

auto apply_w1 = ApplyGradientDescent(scope, w, Cast(scope, 0.01, DT_FLOAT), { grad_outputs[0] });
```

However, what I really want is to have a variable learning rate, which I could update from outside the graph, while avoiding having to create new gradient operations on the graph each time... As such:

```
auto ph = Placeholder(scope, DT_FLOAT));
auto var = Variable(scope, {1}, DT_FLOAT));
auto assignVar = Assign(scope, var, ph));

Tensor newLr(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({1}));
newLr.flat<float>().data()[0] = 0.001;

TF_CHECK_OK(session->Run({{ph, newLr}}, {assignVar}, nullptr));

auto apply = ApplyGradientDescent(scope, w, var, { grad_outputs[0] });
```

The problem is the above fails because ApplyGradientDescent expects a Scalar as alpha, which I don't understand. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is this one of the features that is still being ported from python to c++?

Comment: Unlikely as this has been around since at least 1.12 and i'm on 2.0